# Can we create separate log for every execution using python

Tags: python, testing, logging

```
File1.py
import logging

LOG_FILENAME = "logfile.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG) 
def test_TC01():
logging.log("Testcase1 is executing in file1")

def test_TC02():
logging.log("Testcase2 is executing in file1")

File2.py

def test_TC01():
logging.log("Testcase1 is executing in file2")

def test_TC02():
logging.log("Testcase2 is executing in file2")

File3.py

def test_TC01():
logging.log("Testcase1 is executing in file3")

def test_TC02():
logging.log("Testcase2 is executing in file3")
```

Can we create one reusable class for logging purpose? I want to create only one log for every execution for 3 files and i want to create separate log for every execution.

I don't have much knowledge on python. can someone help me on this.

Comment: Please provide more details on how you use these modules. And what is `dev`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Which details you are expecting. I want to create common log 3 files and for every execution i want to generate a new log based on time stamp